# Bash script variable syntax

Tags: bash, variables, syntax

I am new to bash scripting. I am trying to write a script which searches for a four letter/number string which has the form 'Jxxx' where x can be A-Z or 0-9. How do I represent this as a variable in bash?
Thanks very much

Comment: You should read some regex tutorial. Your problem is typical regex search problem. e.g. `grep 'J[0-9A-Z]\{3\}' file`

Answer (score 1):

Variables just contain static content in Bash - what you want is a **regular expression**, aka. "regex", which in your case would be simplest expressed as `J[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]`. You can use this with many programs to match text in files:

```
$ cat > my.txt << EOF
JAA
JAAA
JZ0Z
J00
foo
EOF
$ grep 'J[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]' my.txt
JAAA
JZ0Z
```

or filenames:

```
$ touch JAA JAAA JZ0Z J00 foo
$ find . -name 'J[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]'
./JZ0Z
./JAAA
```